# Unity - Change vertex colors

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have the following code in update callback

```
    Mesh m = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().sharedMesh;
    Color[] newColors = new Color[m.vertices.Length];
    for (int vertexIndex = 0; vertexIndex < newColors.Length; vertexIndex++)
    {
        newColors[vertexIndex] = new Color(Random.value, Random.value, Random.value, 1.0f);

    }
    m.colors = newColors;
```

In the scene i have 3D game object as sphere, I am not seeing any change in the color when i play the scene. Please suggest

Output is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your code is good.

Most built-in Shaders don't display vertex colors, so you have to use one of "Particle" shaders, or modify/create your own.

That's it.

.

Something is not right, right? :D

Particle shaders look bad on 3D meshes like your Sphere, due to it's poor alpha layers rendering.

You have to create second, a bit smaller object, and assign something that blocks/hides the empty space inside your main one.

For example:

```
Shader "Custom/VertexLitBlendedWithZ" {
Properties {
    _EmisColor ("Emissive Color", Color) = (.2,.2,.2,0)
    _MainTex ("Particle Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
}

Category {
    Tags { "Queue"="Transparent" "IgnoreProjector"="True" "RenderType"="Transparent" }
    Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
    Cull Off ZWrite On Fog { Color (0,0,0,0) }

    Lighting On
    Material { Emission [_EmisColor] }
    ColorMaterial AmbientAndDiffuse

    SubShader {
        Pass {
            SetTexture [_MainTex] {
                combine texture * primary
            }
        }

    }
}
}
```

Now everything renders as it should.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I am new to the unity, can you share full code or steps so that i can experiment.

Comment: I have done some experiment in three.js with vertex coloring, you can have a look at my portal , https://rt-viz.firebaseapp.com/ , I am trying to apply vertex coloring in unity mesh.

Comment: If you haven't already, you should read about materials in unity docs: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Materials.html

Comment: Creating, assigning to meshes, and using custom shaders. This knowledge is everywhere, there's no need to write all those steps here.

Comment: The rest is my answer above. If you have any doubts, feel free to ask. Hope you'll find my answer useful. Good luck!